# SQL Server replace NULL by the last value

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I want to find a way to replace NULL values by the last not NULL value.
I have a table like :

```
Date        Cost
2017-01-01  18.6046511
2017-01-03  22.9787234
2017-01-03  NULL
2017-01-12  18.8584937
2017-01-16  19.1827852
2017-01-16  NULL
2017-01-19  NULL
2017-02-21  NULL
2017-03-04  24.0597622
2017-03-28  NULL
2017-04-17  33.5398414
2017-04-17  NULL
```

I want to replace NULL value by the last not NULL value
so the result will be like:

```
Date        Cost
2017-01-01  18.6046511
2017-01-03  22.9787234
2017-01-03  22.9787234
2017-01-12  18.8584937
2017-01-16  19.1827852
2017-01-16  19.1827852
2017-01-19  19.1827852
2017-02-21  19.1827852
2017-03-04  24.0597622
2017-03-28  24.0597622
2017-04-17  33.5398414
2017-04-17  33.5398414
```

Comment: https://tomaztsql.wordpress.com/2018/08/05/filling-propagading-empty-values-with-last-nonnull-value-using-t-sql/

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following query by creating a Group Using Window Frame (GUWF). [source link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/filling-in-missing-values-using-the-t-sql-window-frame/).

```
create table MyTable ([dtDate] date, Cost decimal(18, 6))
insert into MyTable values 
('2017-01-01',  18.6046511),
('2017-01-03',  22.9787234),
('2017-01-03',  NULL),
('2017-01-12',  18.8584937),
('2017-01-16',  19.1827852),
('2017-01-16',  NULL),
('2017-01-19',  NULL),
('2017-02-21',  NULL),
('2017-03-04',  24.0597622),
('2017-03-28',  NULL),
('2017-04-17',  33.5398414),
('2017-04-17',  NULL)

SELECT dtDate, Cost = MAX(Cost) OVER (PARTITION BY c)
FROM
(
    SELECT dtDate, Cost
        ,c = count(Cost) OVER (ORDER BY dtDate)
    FROM MyTable
) a
ORDER BY dtDate;
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=09389b77e20883d982b85b51cbddb4d2)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please check this [db<>fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de184083a6aa7d152c9b1567275e0836) that works with the decreasing cost values also.

Answer (score 2):

If current value is null, then return first value where date is lower or equal to current date.

```
SELECT *, ISNULL(Value, (SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM SomeTable WHERE Date <= t.Date AND Value IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID DESC))
FROM SomeTable t
```

This is not tested, just written from head.

Comment: Doing a subquery in a select is very bad for performance

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts - thats a massive generalisation which is frequently not true.